# Content from external iframe not loaded until page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

for several days I'm struggling with putting ads to my personal website and since I'm already out of ideas I would like to ask you for help. Any idea or suggestion is highly welcome because I'm really desperate.

I got a short JS code from the ad network to put on my website. The code basically loads, dynamically creates iframe and loads ad content to this iframe from the ad company (more or less standard approach).

However in my case the iframe is created but the content is not loaded until I refresh the page one or more times.

The symptoms I identified are following:

- it happens only on my site, ads from the same ad network work fine on different webs in the same browser
- I'm able to reproduce the same behavior on different browsers, devices and operating systems = not local issue
- the problem is not in my CMS (Wordpress)

To isolate the problem and make sure that the issue is not in any of Wordppress plugins or Wordpress itself I created simple test page on the same domain out of Wordpress:

https://www.beapple.pro/test.html

Just pure HTML, short text and the ad code. When you open this page the ad is not loaded on the first load, it must be refreshed.

I also found out that if I disable cross-domain tracking prevention in the browser (e.g. Safari) it works fine. However the ads from this network should work even if no cookie is set. And after several refreshes of the page it works as well no matter if the cookie is set or not. As I said ads from the same ad network work on different sites fine, therefore the dependency on cookies is probably not important. If the ad is finally displayed, it stays fine for some minutes and then it disappears again (probably cache).

I also tracked the HTTP request / response communication when the iframe is loaded. I found out that that the response contains empty HTML code if the ad is not displayed (at least this is what browser shows me in debug mode). The ad company told me that the request probably times out due to slow connection however I do not believe them since I verified the same behavior from different places and different connections.

The behavior is very strange and despite my effort I did not find root cause of the issue. If it happened only on my machine, I would say it is a local problem, if I had the same problem on all webs, I would say it is problem of the ad company. However it can be reproduced on any device (with blocking of 3rd party cookies enabled) but only on my domain.

Please help, you are my last resort. Thanks a lot for any input.

UPDATE: Any workaround is welcome as well. I did not figure out how to refresh the iframe reliably. Since I cannot access the inner html of the iframe due to browser security rules, it is hard to find out if there is any content or not = if refresh worked.

Comment: This is why I dislike working with iframes directly.  They can be unpredictable.  Try checking if you have cache enabled in WP.  Or check if you have other http connections trying to process when your page loads.

Comment: You can also observe the same behavior on the real web on Wordpress, e.g. https://www.beapple.pro/aplikace/1-blocker-x-vice-nez-blokovani-reklamy/

Comment: @klewis The test page is out of WP as standalone HTML page in root folder of my hosting, therefore any cache is out of question in this case. Unfortunately the iframe is created by JS of the ad company, I cannot do it differently

Comment: You might want to try some sort of output buffering: [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: That could be part of the problem.  Is there any way the iframe can load onto page only when the window is ready? Perhaps that will make the difference. Loading it anytime sooner could be the issue.

Comment: @klewis I tried to create a script which refreshes those ad iframes after page is loaded. However it did not work as expected. Even if the ad content was loaded from the ad server with every refresh (= not from briwser cache), the content of the iframe was always returned empty (= response 200 OK, but empty). I tried several refreshes with delay e.g. 500 ms but with no luck. The ad is loaded only when I refresh the whole page but it is of course ugly solution from usability perspective.